# Retrofit: Sending multiple requests and get responses in same order, how to?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

Scenario:
 Initially I send a Post request to server and server initiates an operation  there. Now I need to get some data from server after the completion of the  operation . So I need to check the status of the process by sending requests again and again(maximum 5) until I get "success" status from the server. How can I chain these requests using Retrofit?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using "plain" Retrofit (using `Callback`s) or the RxJava version? If the latter, have a look at `flatMap`/`concatMap` and `retryWhen`.

Comment: .Thanks for the suggestion David. I am using Callbacks in Retrofit only? Any way to do that?

Comment: In that case I think you'll have to bite the bullett and have: (1) one `Callback` for  your first request, (2) in the `success` method start the other request, which has (3) it's own `Callback`. In the `success` method of that, you are done, but in the `failure` method you'd have to re-call the second request, maybe adding a timeout (with a `TimerTask`) before you do. Ask again if you run into any trouble!

Comment: Thanks a lot David for the suggestion. Let me try that (with a TimerTask). But let me ask you one thing, In this scenario, is 'RxJava ' the best way to do?. I mean, do I need to imlpement RXJava to support this scenario, in my requests?

Comment: I am certain you *can* do it without RxJava. But it probably won't be as elegant as `myFirstRequest().flatMap(mySecondRequest().retryWhen(retryFunction)).subscribe()`. If you have more cases like this, I'd really encourage you to give RxJava a shot!

Comment: Thanks David, for the suggestion